# Finding null records for Json return string

Tags: json, list, rest, asp.net-web-api2, ienumerable

I have created a WEB API using `MySQL` DB. On the basis of data I am sending `YES` or `NO`.

**How API is working?**

I am passing a meter serial number and a date time. The API receives both of them. +- The minutes in time and display all the records withing that time.

**What's the issue ?**

**I am always getting `YES` response regarding whatever I sent the API.**

Below is my code

```
 public class ResponseChecker
{
    public string Response { get; set; }

    public ResponseChecker(IEnumerable result)
    {

        if (result.ToString().ToList().Count()>0)
        {
            Response = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            Response = "No";
        }
    }
}

public MDCEntities medEntitites = new MDCEntities();
 try
        {
            var before = dt.AddMinutes(-5);
            var after = dt.AddMinutes(5);

            var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd
                         .Where(m =>
                         m.zdjh == msn &&
                         m.sjsj >= before &&
                         m.sjsj <= after).Select(m => new { MSN = m.zdjh, DateTime = m.sjsj, Signal_Strength = m.xhqd }).Distinct();


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = new ResponseChecker(result)});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
```

The response I am getting is like below

```
{
"data": {
    "Response": "YES"    }
}
```

I have tried each and everything for checking the any null record in the `result` as I tired `== null` , `!= null`, `.Any()` etc. But still unable to get my desired result.

Also the part `result.ToString().ToList().Count()>0` is always giving me `true`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried printing what's the result of this?

```
if (result.ToString().ToList().Count()>0)
```

You can do:

```
var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd
                     .Where(m =>
                     m.zdjh == msn &&
                     m.sjsj >= before &&
                     m.sjsj <= after).Select(m => new { MSN = m.zdjh, DateTime = m.sjsj, Signal_Strength = m.xhqd }).Distinct().ToList();
```

And just validate the ammount of result with a simple count.

Comment: `result.ToString().ToList().Count()>0` it's always sending me `true`

Comment: write return result.ToString().ToList().Count() and print it. then write result.ToString(); and print it. You're interpreting a var as a string, then as a list and counting - do you see what's wrong with this sentence?

Comment: Yes I have corrected it now. You are a life savor :)

Comment: Glad It helped!